# Pass data from model clean function to template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Is there a way to pass a dictionary of errors from `def clean` function to the template ? I think that context_processors can do the trick but not sure if its the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

its a Using context processors is one method for doing this.
A Python function called a context processor has two arguments: the request object and a dictionary holding the context information. The template will have additional variables that can later be added to the context.
Here is an example how to transmit a dictionary of errors from a form's clean function to the template using a context processor:
`forms.py`

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        errors = {}
        # perform validation and add errors to the errors dictionary
        if errors:
            self.add_error(None, errors)
```

`context_processor.py`

```
def form_errors(request):
    if hasattr(request, 'form_errors'):
        return {'form_errors': request.form_errors}
    return {}
```

Add the following in `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'myapp.context_processors.form_errors',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

`views.py`

```
def my_view(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # do something with the form data
        pass
    else:
        request.form_errors = form.errors
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

`index.html`

```
{% for field, errors in form_errors.items %}
    {% for error in errors %}
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Using this method, the form errors variable may be used to retrieve the errors dictionary in the template.
There are another alternative you can use; `django messages framework`

Comment: I am talking about the clean method In models.Model , not in form

Comment: It is actually the same process, but you define your `clean` function in model instead of forms

Comment: I dont think its the same because you cannot get form errors on model

Answer (score 0):

This is how you implement it through model.
`models.py`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def clean(self):
        errors = {}
        # perform validation and add errors to the errors dictionary
        if errors:
            raise ValidationError(errors)
```

`views.py`

```
def my_view(request):
    my_model_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
    try:
        my_model_instance.clean()
    except ValidationError as e:
        request.model_errors = e.message_dict
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'my_model_instance': my_model_instance})
```

`context_processor.py`

```
def model_errors(request):
    if hasattr(request, 'model_errors'):
        return {'model_errors': request.model_errors}
    return {}
```

`settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'myapp.context_processors.model_errors',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

`index.html`

```
<!-- index.html -->
{% for field, errors in model_errors.items %}
    {% for error in errors %}
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```